# How can I compute the correlation between two matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, correlation

In Wireless communication, we define a channel matrix `H` to be a matrix of size `N` by `M`, where `N` is the number of receive antennas at some receiver and `M` is the number of transmit antennas at some transmitter.

Assume we have two channel instances,  `H1` and `H2`, and Id like to study the correlation between these two channels in MATLAB.

For simplicity of exposition, assume

```
H1  = randn (8,64);
H2= randn(8,64)
```

then is it correct to say the correlation between the two matrices is

```
abs(H1' *H2)
```

Sorry for a long post, basically I just want to find how much correlated the two matrices are in Matlab..

Answer (score 2):

use [`corr2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html)

```
coef = corr2(H1, H2)
```

if you don't have `corr2` use:

```
H1 = randn(1000,1000);
H2 = randn(1000,1000);

H1 = H1 - mean(H1(:));
H2 = H2 - mean(H2(:));
coef = sum(sum(H1.*H2))/sqrt(sum(sum(H1.*H1))*sum(sum(H2.*H2)))
```

Comment: Requires `Image Processing Toolbox` which he doesn't necessarily have